# the use of If function in excel 2016 Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to use if function in excel (2016, MAC) to display two value based on the value of wind direction:

- If the angle is between 90 and 180: use this formula 180 - angle
- If the angle is between 180 and 270: use this formula angle- 180.

I used this function =if((angle>=90,angle<=180), 180-angle, if(angle>=180,angle<=270), angle -180)) but it does not work! any help

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. In what way does it not work? Could you post a screenshot and describe what you are seeing vs. what you are expecting?

Comment: `if( and(angle>=90,angle<=180), ..., ...)`

Comment: what if the angle is less than 90 ??

Answer (score 0):

When there are multiple conditions all need to be True or False, we may use IF function with And.

Please use function `=IF(AND(angle>=90,angle<=180),180-angel,IF(AND(angle>=180,angle<=270),angle-180)).`

[image]

Please note, the function is apply to the angle between 90 and 270, otherwise we will get as False as result.